# ClassNotFoundException in navigation graph android

Tags: android, kotlin, classnotfoundexception, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I saw this crash over firebase and it is not reporducible in the emulator of same OS.
Not sure what is causing it. Crash is occuring in samsung M32 OS 11.

The crash is

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.octave.data.offer.Classes
```

This is the navigation graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/offer_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/offersFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/availableOfferDetailFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.offers.available.detail.AvailableOfferDetailFragment"
    android:label="fragment_available_offer_detail"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_available_offer_detail">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_availableOfferDetailFragment_to_applyOfferFragment"
        app:destination="@id/applyOfferFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="classes"
            app:argType="com.octave.data.offer.Classes[]" />
        <argument
            android:name="paymentPlans"
            app:argType="com.octave.data.offer.PaymentPlan[]" />
        <argument
            android:name="offerName"
            app:argType="string" />
    </action>
</fragment></navigation>
```

And my data classes are as follows

```
@Parcelize
data class Classes(
val id: Int,
val name: String,
val totalEquity: Int,
val reservedEquity: Int,
val expectedReturn: Float,
val subscribed: Int
):Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class PaymentPlan(
val id: String?=null,
val name: String,
var payment: Int,
val date: String
):Parcelable
```

Answer (score 5):

It could be related to obfuscation. Here's a rule for any class annotated with @Parcelize:

-keep @kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize public class *

Note it's for kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize and not for the deprecated alternative kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize.

Comment: This helped me with the same issue, I think this should be accepted answer

Comment: life saver, thanks